# Angular 2 : Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. - How can I turn this into a factory method?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

After installing Angular-cli I am getting this error:

```
Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a refer
ence to an exported function (position 55:19 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in C:/TM-2013/Debt/Debt Platform/Code/main/Think.Debt.Presentation/deb-explorer-with-angular
-cli/src/app/app.module.ts
```

In my App.Module.ts it does not like this section of code:

providers: [

```
//   These are needed throughout the site    
AppConfigService,

{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: configServiceFactory, deps: [AppConfigService], multi: true },
{
  provide: HttpService,
  useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
    return new HttpService(backend, options);
  },
  deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
}
```

],

EDIT:

with the .load

```
  { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: (config: AppConfigService) => () => config.load(), deps: [AppConfigService], multi: true },
    {
      provide: HttpService,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
        return new HttpService(backend, options);
      },
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }
```

Is it possible to turn this into a factory class as it does not like this current usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do exactly as it suggested:

```
// named exported function
export function httpFactory(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
    return new HttpService(backend, options);
}

export function configServiceFactory(config: AppConfigService) {
    return () => config.load();
}

// after goes declaration of you module with `providers`
// ... skipped ...
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: configServiceFactory, deps: [AppConfigService], multi: true },
{
    provide: HttpService,
    useFactory: httpFactory,  // reference to the function
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
}
// ... skipped ...
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Funky you can use same approach with exported named function for it as well.

Comment: Not quite sure how?

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! You are awesome!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!